# Switch placement of facet_grid labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

How can I change the placement of the labels of `facet_grid()` without switching the formula?

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

data = data.frame(id = 1:10, value = rnorm(100*10))
data = ddply(data, .(id), transform, obs = 1:100)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = obs, y = value, color = factor(id))) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(id ~.)
```

In the following picture, I want the panel text to switch from the right to the top of the panel.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = obs, y = value, color = factor(id))) + 
         geom_line() +
         facet_wrap( ~id, ncol=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is a possibility that I also came up with. Is there a way to make the facet strips slimmer, maybe using `strip.background` & `element_rect`? I am not sure how to use the size argument to `element_rect`.

Comment: Well, you can reduce the size of the strip text: `theme(strip.text=element_text(size=5))`. This would also reduce the size of the strips.