# ggplot2: change placement of facet titles

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have the same problem as in the question: [Switch placement of facet_grid labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127120/switch-placement-of-facet-grid-labels/34675190#34675190)
but using `facet_wrap` i can not get the `scale_fill_manual` to work.

I have coloured and set an order for my data using `factor(data, levels =c())` and then: `scale_fill_manual(values=c()` and `labels=c()`, which works for `facet_grid`. Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: Please post a screen shot at least, and your `sessionInfo()` so we can see your versions.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of ggplot (released just a few days ago) they added a switch argument to facet_wrap, to allow us to switch labels from right to left or top to bottom. Perhaps that is what you are looking for. But it is very hard to say what the problem is with your color scales unless you post your code and output.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same data provided throught the link

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
data = data.frame(id = 1:10, value = rnorm(100*10))
data = ddply(data, .(id), transform, obs = 1:100)
```

fix the desired colors

```
myCol <- c(1:10)
```

and plot with `scale_color_manual()`

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = obs, y = value, color = factor(id))) + 
   geom_line() + facet_wrap( ~id, ncol=1) + scale_color_manual(values=myCol)
```

[image]